# Is there a way to extract an expression from a formula?

Tags: equation-solving

I have an equality:
$$\frac {d_L}{\phi t_1^2}=\frac {d_0}{\phi (t_1 - \Delta t)^2}$$
I can manually extract $d_L - d_0$ from this equation by expanding and re-arranging.  Is there any way to do this in Mathematica?  Ideally, I'd like **Solve** to work like this:

Solve$[\frac {d_L}{\phi t_1^2}==\frac {d_0}{\phi (t_1 - \Delta t)^2}, d_L - d_0]$
which would render:
$$d_L - d_0=d_L(\frac {2 \Delta t}{t_1}-\frac {\Delta t^2}{t_1^2})$$

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! People here generally like users to post code as Mathematica code instead of images or TeX, so they can copy-paste it. It makes it convenient for them and more likely you will get someone to help you.  You may find this [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: Thanks for the hint.  I'm working on it.  Thanks for your patience.

Answer (score 2):

I usually do this by replacing one of the variables in the expression with the difference, then solve, then re-replace.

```
Equal @@ Solve[eq /. d0 -> dl - dl0, dl0][[1, 1]] /. dl0 -> dl - d0
(* -d0 + dl == dl (2 t1 Δt - Δt^2)/t1^2 *)
```

In terms of `dl - d0` and `d0` instead:

```
Equal @@ Solve[eq /. dl -> dl0 + d0, dl0][[1, 1]] /. dl0 -> dl - d0
(* -d0 + dl == d0 (2 t1 Δt - Δt^2)/(t1 - Δt)^2 *)
```

Comment: Yes, I found this to be a simple and elegant way to solve it also.  Thanks.

Comment: For extra credit, how do I use the right part of that equation in another formula?

Comment: @DRAirey1 It depends on what the structure of that other equation is. If it's written in terms of `dl - d0`, just do something like `expr /. dl -> dl0 + d0 /. First@Solve[eq /. d0 -> dl - dl0, dl0]`.

Comment: $d_L - d_0$ is really $\Delta d$, so I want to end up with $$\Delta d = d_L \frac {2 t_1 \Delta t - \Delta t^2}{(t_1 - \Delta t)^2}$$

Comment: Then replace `dl0` with `\[Delta]d` in everything above, and just use that.

Comment: Thanks.  This works nicely:$$\Delta d = x /. First@Solve[\frac {d_L}{\phi t_1^2}==\frac {d_0}{\phi (t_1 - \Delta t)^2} /. d_0 -> d_L - x, x]$$

Answer (score 1):

```
eq = dl/(ϕ t1^2) == d0/(ϕ (t1 - Δt)^2);
b = Solve[eq, dl][[1]]
a = Solve[eq, d0][[1]]

(dl /. b) - d0 /. a // Expand
```

> ```
> (2 dl Δt)/t1 - (dl Δt^2)/t1^2
> ```